# Magento EE upgrade from 2.2.9 to 2.3.4 issue

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-upgrade, setup-upgrade

I have upgraded Magento from version 2.2.9 to 2.3.4 using the composer.

And run the setup: upgrade, then I am getting below error.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`#sql-27b_17e`, CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ITEM_PARENT_ITEM_ID_QUOTE_ITEM_ITEM_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_item_id`) REFERENCES `quote_item` (`item_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: ALTER TABLE `quote_item` MODIFY COLUMN `item_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT "Item ID", MODIFY COLUMN `quote_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0  COMMENT "Quote ID", MODIFY COLUMN `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT "Updated At", MODIFY COLUMN `product_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NULL   COMMENT "Product ID", MODIFY COLUMN `store_id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NULL   COMMENT "Store ID", MODIFY COLUMN `parent_item_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NULL   COMMENT "Parent Item ID", MODIFY COLUMN `discount_amount` decimal(20, 4)  NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT "Discount Amount", MODIFY COLUMN `base_discount_amount` decimal(20, 4)  NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT "Base Discount Amount", MODIFY COLUMN `tax_amount` decimal(20, 4)  NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT "Tax Amount", MODIFY COLUMN `base_tax_amount` decimal(20, 4)  NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT "Base Tax Amount", MODIFY COLUMN `row_total` decimal(20, 4)  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT "Row Total", MODIFY COLUMN `base_row_total` decimal(20, 4)  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT "Base Row Total", MODIFY COLUMN `row_total_with_discount` decimal(20, 4)  NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT "Row Total With Discount", MODIFY COLUMN `base_tax_before_discount` decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Base Tax Before Discount", MODIFY COLUMN `tax_before_discount` decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Tax Before Discount", MODIFY COLUMN `price_incl_tax` decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Price Incl Tax", MODIFY COLUMN `base_price_incl_tax` decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Base Price Incl Tax", MODIFY COLUMN `row_total_incl_tax` decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Row Total Incl Tax", MODIFY COLUMN `base_row_total_incl_tax` decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Base Row Total Incl Tax", MODIFY COLUMN `discount_tax_compensation_amount` decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Discount Tax Compensation Amount", MODIFY COLUMN `base_discount_tax_compensation_amount` decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Base Discount Tax Compensation Amount", MODIFY COLUMN `gift_message_id` int(11)  NULL   COMMENT "Gift Message ID", ADD CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ITEM_PARENT_ITEM_ID_QUOTE_ITEM_ITEM_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_item_id`) REFERENCES `quote_item` (`item_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE, ADD CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ITEM_QUOTE_ID_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES `quote` (`entity_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE, ADD CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ITEM_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`)  ON DELETE SET NULL

Comment: Surely as an Enterprise customer you can get support from Adobe?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this query:

```
Select item_id from quote_item where parent_item_id is not null and parent_item_id in (select item_id from quote_item)
```

After that, the result will be updated and you need to fix it to **parent_item_id = null**.